# display wheter or not an array entered by the user is unique or not

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ I am making an array based off of user input and displaying whether the array is unique or not. my initial thought is I have to end up creating another array to store values and then compare the elements. My code compiles without errors but does not do what I want it to do. I can't used advanced methods such as hashmaps or vectors. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int myArray[6];
    string name;
    int i, k;
    int ov = 0;
    int newVal = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++) 
{
    cout << "Enter number a number: ";
    cin >> myArray[index];
}//end loop for

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    ov = myArray[i];
}
for (k = i + 1; k < 6; k++)
{
    if (ov == myArray[k])
    {
        newVal = 1;
    }
}

  if (newVal == 1)
{
    cout << "Not all unique";
}

  else
{
    cout << "All unique";
}



   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at your first for loop. It is meaningless. You simply end up with ov containing the last value

Comment: so I should completely get rid of it?

Comment: Now i get what you are trying to do. Your two loops should be nested right?

Comment: that is the idea...I just don't think I am executing what I want to do right. My thought is to store the values into another array to compare if they are equal to the previous entry.

Comment: No need to. Your two loops are not nested the way your code is right now. you should use the syntax correctly like this: for() {  for() { ...} }

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a unique array? An array different from all previous ones? Or should all values inside an array be unique?

Comment: damn...that definatly fixed it haha thanks

Comment: Are you "only" interested in getting this thing done or is there some specific topic you are supposed to/want to learn?

Comment: Arrays are the first tricky thing I have encountered...I just wanted to make sure I was in the right direction by my logic.

Comment: Fine by me ;-) Just keep in mind that many of those problems are somewhat "solved problems" and you should (imho) look up the existing solutions. Something resembling your solution would be http://rextester.com/QAIZ89068

Comment: yeah I couldn't use that that's to advanced for what we're doing, but there were similar posts I just couldn't figure out for the world why it wouldn't work, I guess an extra { makes all the difference!